# Turning on and off an output with just one button and a FlipFlop

Tags: flipflop

I am trying to make a circuit with the following characteristics: If I press the switch once and then immediately release the circuit activates the output and leaves it activated. If I press it again and release the button, it deactivates the output and leaves it disabled and so on. But in the circuit that I mounted (pictured below) the output is activated only while I hold the button pressed. Can anyone tell me what I might be missing?

[image]

Comment: Presumably pin 7 grounded (not as shown in the schematic).  Also, it probably isn't causing the problem, but you should have some series resistance between the switch and the capacitor so that you don't run too much current through the switch when the button is first pressed.

Comment: The logic looks OK (assuming pin 7 is grounded as crj11 noted). This only occurs when you activate? Never when you deactivate? If it happens in both directions, could be a bounce/input hysteresis issue.